# pygame sprite wall collision

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I am working on a platform game in python and pygame. The entire code can be found at "https://github.com/C-Kimber/FBLA_Game". The issue I am having is with the collision between the player sprite and wall sprites, specifically the corners. When the player is pressing a x movement key and they jump, the player either does not move, or gets stuck. Here is the collision sample:

```
def wallCollisions(self):

    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)

    for block in block_hit_list:


        if self.rect.bottom >= block.rect.top and self.rect.bottom <= block.rect.top + 15:  # Moving down; Hit the top side of the wall
            if self.rect.right > block.rect.left:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
                self.yvel = 0
                self.onGround = True
                self.jumps = 1
        elif self.rect.top <= block.rect.bottom and self.rect.top >= block.rect.bottom - 15:  # Moving up; Hit the bottom side of the wall
            self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
            self.yvel = 0
        if self.rect.right >= block.rect.left and self.rect.right <= block.rect.left + 15:  # Moving right; Hit the left side of the wall
            if self.rect.bottom > block.rect.top+15:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left#+1
                self.xvel = 0
        elif self.rect.left <= block.rect.right and self.rect.left >= block.rect.right - 15:  # Moving left; Hit the right side of the wall
            self.rect.left = block.rect.right#-1
            self.xvel = 0 = block.rect.right#-1
            self.xvel = 0
```

I've included images on what is happening and what I want. [image]

I have attempted other methods, such as using velocity as determining factos for collision, but this is what is working the best so far. If you could provide a solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One assumption you're making in your code is that you can collide the player against each block independently. But should the collision properties of a black depend on other blocks that it's next to? For example, should you be able to land on a block (onGround = true) that has another block on top of it?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354171/add-scrolling-to-a-platformer-in-pygame/14357169#14357169). While the topic is actually different, it's a working example of how you could do the collision detection (look at the `collide` function). The idea is to check for collision twice, once for the x, and once for the y axis.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you to user sloth! The question he linked gave me some much needed clarity. It took me a bit but I implemented it. I created a function for the collision.

```
def wallColl(self, xvel, yvel, colliders):
    for collider in colliders:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, collider):
            if xvel > 0:
                self.rect.right = collider.rect.left
                self.xvel = 0
            if xvel < 0:
                self.rect.left = collider.rect.right
                self.xvel = 0
            if yvel < 0:
                self.rect.bottom = collider.rect.top
                self.onGround = True
                self.jumps = 3
                self.yvel = 0
            if yvel > 0:
                self.yvel = 0
                self.rect.top = collider.rect.bottom
```

And then I call them in my update function.

```
def update(self):
    self.rect.x += self.xvel
    # self.walls is an array of sprites.
    self.wallColl(self.xvel, 0, self.walls) 

    self.rect.y -= self.yvel
    self.onGround = False
    self.wallColl(0, self.yvel, self.walls)

    self.wallCollisions()
    if self.otherplayers != None:
        self.playerCollisions()

    # Gravity
    if self.onGround == False:
        self.yvel-=.0066*self.mass

    self.boundries(highbound, lowbound, leftbound, rightbound)
    self.down = False
```

The actual useage in my game makes usability near perfect. Not 100% though, this is not a perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle collisions with walls is to move the player rect or sprite along the x-axis first, check if it collides with a wall and then set its `self.rect.right = wall.rect.left` if it's moving to the right or `self.rect.left = wall.rect.right` if it's moving to the left. Afterwards you do the same with the y-axis. You have to do the movement separately, otherwise you wouldn't know the direction and how to reset the position of the rect.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, walls):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.pos = Vector2(x, y)  # Position vector.
        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)  # Velocity vector.
        self.walls = walls  # A reference to the wall group.

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.wall_collisions()

    def wall_collisions(self):
        """Handle collisions with walls."""
        self.rect.centerx = self.pos.x
        for wall in pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False):
            if self.vel.x > 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            elif self.vel.x < 0:
                self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
            self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx

        self.rect.centery = self.pos.y
        for wall in pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False):
            if self.vel.y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
            elif self.vel.y < 0:
                self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
            self.pos.y = self.rect.centery


class Wall(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('sienna1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    walls = pg.sprite.Group()

    wall = Wall(100, 200, 300, 30)
    wall2 = Wall(230, 70, 30, 300)
    walls.add(wall, wall2)
    all_sprites.add(wall, wall2)

    player = Player(300, 300, walls)
    all_sprites.add(player)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_w]:
            player.vel.y = -3
        elif keys[pg.K_s]:
            player.vel.y = 3
        else:
            player.vel.y = 0
        if keys[pg.K_a]:
            player.vel.x = -3
        elif keys[pg.K_d]:
            player.vel.x = 3
        else:
            player.vel.x = 0

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elif self.rect.top <= block.rect.bottom and self.rect.top >= block.rect.bottom - 15:  # Moving up; Hit the bottom side of the wall
        self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
        self.yvel = 0
```

Shouldn't `yvel` be set to a positive number to make it go up?