# Pygame Cass Function for creating platforms without manually creating every single platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pygame

I am creating a platform game and I am trying to shorten my code by creating a class for the platforms. However, my code doesn't run and I am unsure on what the error that's displayed.

My code:

```
import pygame,sys,time,random
pygame.init()

#COLOUR
light_red=(255,99,71)

res_x,res_y=800,600
display = pygame.display.set_mode((res_x,res_y))
display.fill(black)
pygame.display.update()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
fps=60

class Rect:
        def __int__(self,color,x,y,l,h,th):
                self.color=color
                self.x=x
                self.y=y
                self.l=l
                self.h=h
                self.th=th


rect1=pygame.draw.rect(display,Rect('light_red','random.randrange(0,150)','150','300','50','5'))



 pygame.display.update()
```

The error shown:

```
    rect1=pygame.draw.rect(display,Rect('light_red','random.randrange(0,150)','150','300','50','5'))
TypeError: Rect() takes no arguments
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You've misspelled `__init__` in your `Rect` class.
2. [`pygame.draw.rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) takes a surface, a color and a rect-style object which can be a `pygame.Rect`, a list or a tuple with four elements. Your custom `Rect` class won't work, but you could pass a tuple:

   ```
   rect = Rect(light_red, random.randrange(0,150), 150, 300, 50, 5)
   rect1n = pygame.draw.rect(display, rect.color, (rect.x, rect.y, rect.l, rect.h))
   ```
3. The arguments should not be strings:

   ```
   Rect(light_red, random.randrange(0,150), 150, 300, 50, 5)
   ```
4. You could just give your `Rect` a `draw` method in which you call `pygame.draw.rect` (also give it a `self.rect` attribute instead of the separate `self.x`, etc. attributes):

   ```
   class Rect:
       def __init__(self,color,x,y,l,h,th):
           self.color = color
           self.th = th
           # Just create a pygame.Rect object to store the attributes.
           self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, l, h)

       def draw(self, surface):
           pygame.draw.rect(display, self.color, self.rect)

   rect = Rect(light_red, random.randrange(0,150), 150, 300, 50, 5)

   # Then draw it like this in the while loop.
   rect.draw(display)
   ```

---

I recommend checking out how [pygame sprites and sprite groups](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=en#section_13) work and then turn your platform class into a `pygame.sprite.Sprite` subclass. If you want to see a simple platformer example with sprites and groups, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069743/6220679).

---

Also, better choose another name for your `Rect` class, since there's already the `pygame.Rect` class.

Comment: Omg thank you so much . You have helped me by leaps and bounds. Thx